# Printing maps of using standard input method in java: Avoiding the warning on unused local variables

Tags: java, pmd

I'm coding a program WorldMap.java that reads boundary information of a country (or other geographic entity) from standard input and plots the results to standard drawing. A country consists of a set of regions (e.g., states, provinces, or other administrative divisions), each of which is described by a polygon.

For the input format-
The first line contains two integers: width and height. The remaining part of the input is divided into regions-

The first entry in each region is the name of the region. For simplicity, names will not contain spaces.
The next entry is an integer specifying the number of vertices in the polygon describing the region.
Finally, the region contains the x- and y-coordinates of the vertices of the polygon. [Snapshot of text file used for standard input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KMno.jpg).

My code works perfectly but I get a pmd warning when submitting my assignment-

```
WorldMap.java:16: Avoid unused local variables, such as 'name'. [UnusedLocalVariable]
```

How can i modify my code to avoid the pmd warning? Here's the code-

```
 int width = StdIn.readInt();
    int height = StdIn.readInt();
    StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering();
    StdDraw.setCanvasSize(width, height);
    StdDraw.setXscale(0.0, width);
    StdDraw.setYscale(0.0, height);
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
        String name = StdIn.readString();
        int vertices = StdIn.readInt();
        double[] x = new double[vertices];
        double[] y = new double[vertices];
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
            x[i] = StdIn.readDouble();
            y[i] = StdIn.readDouble();
        }
        StdDraw.polygon(x, y);
    }
    StdDraw.show();
```

PMD is an open source static source code analyzer that reports on issues found within application code. Feel free to google for more details.

Comment: What is a _pmd warning_? In the code you posted, you assign a value to local variable `name` but you never do anything with it. Can't you just remove the following line: `String name = StdIn.readString();` ?

Comment: @Abra, if I remove the line of string name, I get this error- `Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: attempts to read an 'int' value from standard input, but the next token is "??????????_??????"
        at StdIn.readInt(StdIn.java:367)
        at WorldMap.main(WorldMap.java:16)`  it is because the next data is string and not int. Is there some way I can skip to the next input data? Since that would solve the problem

Comment: So call the method but ignore its return value, i.e. `StdIn.readString();` (In other words, just delete the `String name = `) By the way, I still don't know what a _pmd warning_ is.

Comment: @Abra _PMD is an open source static source code analyzer that reports on issues found within application code. PMD includes built-in rule sets and supports the ability to write custom rules. PMD does not report compilation errors, as it only can process well-formed source files._ I just copy pasted it. You can search it on google for more details. And thanks for the help :) .

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a String value in name variable in the line below but you are not using this String value anywhere in the code.
`String name = StdIn.readString();`. If you are not using name variable for anything that means you don't need to read value in it or in other words you don't need to declare it. That's the reason PMD gives you a warning -- either you have missed to use the variable or you can remove the variable the output of the program will not have any difference.

Comment: if I remove the line of string name, I get this error- `Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: attempts to read an 'int' value from standard input, but the next token is "??????????_??????"         at StdIn.readInt(StdIn.java:367)         at WorldMap.main(WorldMap.java:16)` it is because the next data is string and not int. Is there some way I can skip to the next input data? Since that would solve the problem

Comment: You need to read the String but no need to assign it to any variable. Just change the code as below:
'''
    ...
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
        StdIn.readString();
        int vertices = StdIn.readInt();
    ...
'''